# validation_errors in CI is not friendly

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have my form validation in CI.I want to display the validation_errors() message,but i think it's not a friendly message.It looked like this:

```
%3Cp%3EThe%20First%20Name%20field%20can%20not%20exceed%201%20characters%20in%20length.%3C
```

Any idea how to display the message? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use urldecode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

```
public function post_message($message)
{
      echo urldecode($message);
}
```